# linux expect command

Tags: regex, linux, expect

I am using the linux 'expect' to automate passwords.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set password passwd 
spawn scp * root@ip_address:.
expect "password:" 
send "$password\r" 
expect eof
output :
spawn scp * root@ip_address:. 
root@ip_address's password: *: No such file or directory
```

Looks like the regular expression '*' is not recognized. I know of the ssh-key gen method to set up keys but 'expect' command is more suitable for my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is not a valid regular expression, and in the context you're using it, it would be a wildcard.  The `spawn` will interpret it literally and pass it as an argument to the program you're starting.

If you want the asterisk globbed, you'll have to get a shell to do it for you:

```
spawn sh -c "scp * root@foo"
```

Comment: the other choice is to let expect do the glob expansion with the `glob` command